# Checking AppState prior to dispatching Redux Action?

Tags: redux, action, store, dispatch

Say I have a Redux store that keeps track of an AppState that is comprised of a single 'color' variable as a string.

```
initialState = {
    color: 'red'
}
```

And an Action for updating this:

```
const SET_COLOR = 'SET_COLOR';

function setColor(color) {
    return { type: SET_COLOR, color };
}
```

And say I have some sort of input that allows the user to set the color to whatever they please. (How this is done is irrelevant)

```
let newColor = <got new color somehow>
```

Now lets say the user inputs 'red' (the same as the current state). Should I care if the *newColor* and the current *color* differ? Ie, should I first check the store to see if the *newColor* is different than the old *color*, and only dispatch the *setColor* action IFF the color is different? Or should I just dispatch the setColor action, regardless if there's a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would say do the easiest thing and just call `setColor` again. The reason is that it keeps your logic more straightforward. Any time the user changes the color via an input field, then your code will dispatch the action. Now, you only need to write test case to verify this behavior. This may sound trivial but 1) it adds up and 2) you would also have to test the case of rapidly switching back and forth between two colors to be sure your code works.

I would filter out the `newColor()` dispatch if there was an explicit reason to do so, such as:

- Performance shows it is needed
- The UI behavior needs to be different in these two scenarios to let the user know they haven't changed anything
- changing the color has knock on side effects of related data that are undesirable (for example, changing the color might reset the shape to a triangle)

Or similar. The point being, do the simple thing by default unless there's a reason not to.

Redux actions are designed to be cheap. Don't be afraid of dispatching. It's a similar philosophy to React. Render, render, render, and let the framework do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it correctly (preferably using a good immutable data type for your state, e.g. immutable.js), then the new state returned by your reducer is equal to the previous state and the component will not re-render (provided you have a PureComponent or the componentShouldUpdate returns false because the state hasn't changed). So dispatching a few extra actions is practically no extra burden on your app.